# Allow dashes for alphanumeric directive in angularjs

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using a directive to allow only alphanumeric characters in my fields. I found this directive to do this:

```
app.directive('onlyAlphabets', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
      function fromUser(text) {
        var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]/g, '');
        console.log(transformedInput);
        if (transformedInput !== text) {
          ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
          ngModelCtrl.$render();
        }
        return transformedInput; // or return Number(transformedInput)
      }
      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
    }
  };
});
```

This works fine. Now I want to allow dashes as well. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

change you regular expression to

```
 text.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z\-\s]/g, '');
```

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ernsptppPYkEtZzF4Ou5?p=preview)

Comment: your code seems to work in the example you have given.But when i use this in my mobile application it does not work.what seems to be the problem?